# Store Scraped WebPage with Python SqlAlchemy

Tags: python, web-scraping, sqlalchemy

I do many look ups and scrapes of webpages and I would like to store the response to those lookups in a database to avoid having to request them again (to improve speed but also to not be a nuisance).  I am using sqlalchemy and python, and I've created an ORM class like below:

```
class MyClass(Base):
    __tablename__ = "myclass"
    url = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    article = Column(String)
```

When creating a new article and adding it to my session, i.e.:

```
session.add(MyClass(url=url,article=requests.get(url).text)
```

I am able to add it to the database.  However, when I query the url's in the database, I receive this message back,

```
OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) unrecognized token: ':' [SQL: u'SELECT http://[mywebsite]]
```

I understand that it is having trouble with the ':' in http:// but am wondering if that is the case, is there any way to use a full web url as the primary key?

Furthermore, what would be the recommended data types, both in terms of storage efficiency and look up efficiency to use for storing a webpage and its corresponding content?

Comment: How are you querying it? Are you doing `session.query(url)`?

Comment: I've been querying as session.query(MyClass.url).all() to get back a list of the url's back.

Comment: That should work. Can you `print(MyClass.url)` before you query to see what it actually is? My bet is that it somehow got reassigned to `http://...`.

Answer (score -1):

I think, escape the url before store it will resolve the problem.

eg:

```
article = requests.get(url).text
url = url.replace(":", "COLON")
session.add(MyClass(url=url,article=article)
```

In a similar way, you can restore it when you take data out

Comment: I agree that this is one way that this could be dealt with, but is something that will take care of 'sanitizing' and restoring so that I can be sure that I don't run into the issue?  I'm surprised that this isn't a more common issue  and would have thought there would be tools/functions available for dealing with this already...

Comment: You can make it what you need. maybe the tool you create can help someone else : )

Comment: You definitely do not need to escape colons in the values. This answer is so misguided that I don't know how to correct whatever misconceptions that led to it.

Comment: If you think my solution is wrong, plz list the reasons, or put sothing on the table.

Comment: Alright, I'll bite. 1. This will not fix the problem. The problem is not the fact that there are colons in the string. There is no conceivable database that requires symbols to be escaped somehow. If you tried this solution, you'll instead get a "column not found" error, because the problem is the fact that the wrong SQL is being emitted. 2. Even if you were required to escape symbols, is replacing it with `COLON` correct? What if you wanted to store the string `COLON` to begin with?

Comment: You're right. Thanks for your explanation. i learn it from the comment with you.